# Internal server error on phpmyadmin to online website

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, filezilla

Good day, as the pictures show, my website has the following error after an upload I did to have some changes:

```
500 Internal Server Error
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (1045)
```

any help would be appreciated. I am guessing it has something to do with the database not connecting to the website.

[image]
[image: sql]

I was just given this to try to work out and the db config file is:

```
<?php

class config_db {

  public function init() {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mywhitecard;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

    date_default_timezone_set('Hongkong');
    return $db;
  }

}

?>
```

I have access to the database but where do I know the actual username and password needed? I tried to enable each one but I get the exact same 500 Internal Server Error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9cYh.png)

UPDATE:I really dont know why access is denied where clearly it is granted here in the user accounts.

[image: user accounts]

UPDATE 2: I tried to create a new database where I imported the current one and a new user with a name and password, I still get the same 500 internal server error just with the new user getting the access denied.

[image: update2]

Comment: Well, error `Access denied for user` says it all. `where do I know the actual username and password` - ask administrator or create new user if it's good solution and you can't recover credentials

Comment: im told the database is online along with the website how do I do that?, I can access an offline version with localhost and xampp

Comment: Try host=127.0.0.1 sometimes localhost isn't allowed by default.

Comment: updated my answer concerning database users

Comment: You need to use the correct username and password to access that database. Using `root` user to populate website contents is [***Highly Discouraged***](https://espeo.eu/blog/boost-security-mysql-database/)

Comment: ive been struggling for hours already trying to fix the access denied issue, i know its not ideal to use root but i just need to get it working right now. there shouldnt be an access denied problem since in my user accounts clearly shows that global privileges and grant allows root to access the database. Im just highly confused how it does not do what it shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new database. Create a new user. Copy db 'mywhitecard' into new database. Now in the configuration php file use:

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='newdb';charset=utf8', 'newuser', 'newpass');

All the best!!!

Comment: thanks for the advice, tried setting a new username, password and database but I get the same error, just that the new user is the one that gets the access denied this time. I updated my question.

Comment: nevermind, turns out it worked specifically if i use a new username and password connected to the current database name, not a new one. thank you for the straight to the point fix.

Comment: happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a username and password for the database. There are several different types of security (typically default) permissions that you may be running into that will disable the login without password.

I ran into a similar issue a few years ago, but I haven't used php/mysql in a few years, so this may be old/ancient advice :)

Comment: thanks for the advice, tried setting a new username, password and database but I get the same error, just that the new user is the one that gets the access denied this time. I updated my question.